# how to create a new column contained the hash of id column

Tags: php, mysql, sql, hash

I have a table contained 1 column `id`. now I want to create a new column for my table, So I want the data of new column be hashed of `id`. something like this:

```
// my table
+------+
|  id  |
+------+
|  1   |
|  2   |
|  3   |
+------+

// I want this table
+------+------------+
|  id  |   hashed   |
+------+------------+
|  1   |  00320032  |
|  2   |  00330033  |
|  3   |  00340034  |
+------+------------+
```

It should be noted, the `hashed` column is based:

`hash('adler32', '1');  // output: 00320032`

`hash('adler32', '2');  // output: 00330033`

`hash('adler32', '3');  // output: 00340034`

Now, Is it possible to I do that ?

Comment: Does the column `hashed` already exist? Why not just use `SELECT last_insert_id()` as the second parameter in your `hash()` function?

Comment: `hashed` column does not exist, but this is not the problem, I can create it. I want to insert the hash of `id` in into it.

Comment: Can you assign the hashed value to a variable then use that variable in an insert statement? `$hashed = hash('adler32', '1');` then `mysql_query("INSERT INTO your_table_name (id, hashed)
VALUES (null, $hashed)");`??

Comment: @ride_85027 emm, that's not bad, thanks

Comment: I'll add as an answer for future readers then. Let me know how it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Among other possible approaches, you may first fetch all the `id`s, compute the hashed values for each one of them, and re-insert the data back into the table (and avoid duplicates :)

The following is of interest (no error checking is done :)

```
<?php
// Adding the column named 'hashed'
$mysqli->query('ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN (`hashed` INT);');

// Retrieving all the 'id's
$result = $mysqli->query('SELECT id FROM your_table;');
$IDs = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$result->close();

// Assembling the values for a bulk INSERT statement
$values = array();
foreach($IDs as $row) {
    $ID = $row['id'];
    $hashed = hash('adler32', $ID);
    $values[] = "($ID, $hashed)";
}
$values = implode(',', $values);

// Delete to avoid duplicates
$mysqli->query("DELETE FROM your_table;");

// Insert the 'id's and their respective hashed values
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO your_table (id, hashed) VALUES $values;");
```